# Pressing touchscreen triggers mousePressEvent, how do I determine if its a mouse click or a touchscreen click?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, mouseevent, qtgui

I am using Qt 4 on Linux.

I am implementing an application for a touchscreen display and I also have a mouse and keyboard plugged in.

I can implement either mouse or touchscreen, but not both because they interact badly with each other. The main issue is that when I click the mouse OR press the touchscreen I get the following event triggered.

(note: I re-implemented this function so that I can do this things I need)

```
MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    // Handle mouse specific events
}
```

However when I press the touchscreen I also get the same function triggered : (

I therefore cannot distinguish between mouse clicks and touchscreen presses! – how do I get around this issue? how can I determine if it is a mouse click or a touchscreen press?

I have tried looking at the event type, but its always = 2 (mouseClickEvent, but never TouchBegin or such). Currently I am stuck here :(

**EDIT:**

I have looked further into this and implemented somthing like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
...
    qApp->installEventFilter(this);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TouchPadAcceptSingleTouchEvents);
}
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent * pEvent)
{
    switch(pEvent->type())
    {
    case QEvent::TouchBegin:
        qDebug("BEGIN");
        break;
    case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
        qDebug("UPDATE");
        break;
    case QEvent::TouchEnd:
        qDebug("END");
        break;
    case QEvent::MouseMove:
        qDebug("MOUSE");
        break;
   };
   return false;
}
```

I found that I ALWAYS get a MouseMove event regardless of if its a touchscreen input or a mouse input.

I decided that my hardware setup must be such that my touch screen acts like a mouse instead of a touch screen (if that's possible). So I have printed out my /dev/inputs/ to see:

```
root@dm814x-evm:/dev/input# ls -l
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          180 Jan  1  2000 by-id
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          180 Jan  1  2000 by-path
crw-r-----    1 root     root      13,  64 Jan  1  2000 event0
crw-r-----    1 root     root      13,  65 Jan  1  2000 event1
crw-r-----    1 root     root      13,  66 Jan  1  2000 event2
crw-r-----    1 root     root      13,  67 Jan  1  2000 event3
crw-r-----    1 root     root      13,  68 Jan  1  2000 event4
crw-r-----    1 root     root      13,  69 Jan  1  2000 event5
crw-r-----    1 root     root      13,  70 Jan  1  2000 event6
crw-r-----    1 root     root      13,  71 Jan  1  2000 event7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           69 May  1 08:11 keyboard -> /dev/input/by-id/usb-Cypress_WinCE_USB_Keyboard___PS2_Mouse-event-kbd
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            6 Jan  1  2000 keypad -> event2
crw-r-----    1 root     root      13,  63 Jan  1  2000 mice
crw-r-----    1 root     root      13,  32 Jan  1  2000 mouse0
crw-r-----    1 root     root      13,  33 Jan  1  2000 mouse1
crw-r-----    1 root     root      13,  34 Jan  1  2000 mouse2
crw-r-----    1 root     root      13,  35 Jan  1  2000 mouse3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           67 May  1 08:11 touchscreen -> /dev/input/by-id/usb-eGalax_Inc._USB_TouchController-event-joystick

root@dm814x-evm:/dev/input/by-id# ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            9 Jan  1  2000 usb-Cypress_WinCE_USB_Keyboard___PS2_Mouse-event-kbd -> ../event0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            9 Jan  1  2000 usb-Cypress_WinCE_USB_Keyboard___PS2_Mouse-event-mouse -> ../event1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            9 Jan  1  2000 usb-Cypress_WinCE_USB_Keyboard___PS2_Mouse-mouse -> ../mouse0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            9 Jan  1  2000 usb-eGalax_Inc._USB_TouchController-event-joystick -> ../event3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            9 Jan  1  2000 usb-eGalax_Inc._USB_TouchController-event-mouse -> ../event6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            9 Jan  1  2000 usb-eGalax_Inc._USB_TouchController-joystick -> ../mouse1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            9 Jan  1  2000 usb-eGalax_Inc._USB_TouchController-mouse -> ../mouse3
```

It appears to me that the touchscreen is acting as a mouse and therefore will only produce mouse events.

This might now be beyond the scope of this forum?

Comment: I believe this is more a problem with Linux. In the past, when dealing with Windows touch events, there was a setting in the operating system to stop touch events being sent as mouse events. On OSX it just worked as expected. I think you need to look outside of Qt for this as it sounds like the operating system is converting the touch to mouse events before Qt receives them.

Comment: @Merlin069 haha, I just came to that same possible conclusion :) I added some more information under my edit, but I also think this is possibly out of scope for this forum... should I move it to SuperUser?

Answer (score 2):

```
bool eventFilter(QObject * p_obj, QEvent * pevent)
{
  if (pevent->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick ||
   pevent->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress ||
   pevent->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease ||
   pevent->type() == QEvent::Wheel)
  {
     QMouseEvent* pMouseEvent = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(pevent);
     if ((pMouseEvent != NULL) && (pMouseEvent->source() == Qt::MouseEventSource::MouseEventSynthesizedBySystem))
     {
         p_event->ignore();
         return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
 }
```

This will definitely solve your issue. Cheers
Cheers!

Comment: Its a reasonable answer, though I cannot verify it since the project I was working on is loooong gone :o ...ummm, cheers cheers?

Comment: Unfortunately, `Qt::MouseEventSource` was introduced in Qt5.4
Thanks for sharing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( mouseEvent->source() == Qt::MouseEventNotSynthesized )
    ; // MouseButton was pressed
else if( mouseEvent->source() == Qt::MouseEventSynthesizedBySystem )
    ; // touch-event
```

Note that they are also `Qt::MouseEventSynthesizedByQt` and `Qt::MouseEventSynthesizedByApplication`. On my case it worked fine with the two above.